# Put text over picture to fit responsive page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I was trying to put some text over a picture, but I don't want to set `background-image`.

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcLbzap1/1/) to illustrate what I did, and I use bootstrap3.

In the mobile size, it can display fine like

[image]

But if I resize the browser width, it will be broken.

**html**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 visible-sm-block visible-xs-block" style="text-align: center;">
    <p class="competion_text">
        This is inside the competiontion Box!
        <br> Second line
        <br> Third line
    </p>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NajXOdH.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.competion_text {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        top: 252px;
        left: 7px;
        max-width: 225px;
        color: #FFCF83;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.holder {
  position: relative;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.competion_text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFCF83;
  font-size: 10pt;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 visible-sm-block visible-xs-block holder" style="text-align: center;">
        <p class="competion_text">
            This is inside the competiontion Box!
            <br> Second line
            <br> Third line
        </p>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NajXOdH.png">
    </div>
```

I put another class on the parent. (.holder)

Try this. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but what does `margin: 0 auto;` mean?

Comment: Centering element to the parent element. Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
.competion_text {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 252px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 225px;
    color: #FFCF83;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Here is workin [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcLbzap1/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try as below, Set your parent element i.e `.col-xs-12` position as `position:relative` and child i.e. `.competion_text` position as `position:absolute` thus this aligns your text in the center of image, Now I have used CSS `calc() function` in top positing to align it vertically in center and that always stays there.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
.col-xs-12{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}
.col-xs-12 > .competion_text {
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(100% - 30%);
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
        color: #FFCF83;
        font-size: 10pt;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 visible-sm-block visible-xs-block">
        <p class="competion_text">
            This is inside the competiontion Box!
            <br> Second line
            <br> Third line
        </p>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NajXOdH.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as well. Why set `width`,  `height` and 
  `margin` to `auto`?